# How to upload/download a directory using ftp and on ftp CLI? I am using VSFTPD

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

This how I want to upload/download:

```
ftp 10.42.0.1
```

then after entering user and password:

```
ftp >
```

Now if I use `mget`/`get` or `put`/`mput` I am able to copy only files.

*How should I download directories?*

Answer (score 2):

The standard FTP server does not have to implement a directory download according to [RFC959](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc959). Therefore, downloading an entire directory is performed by:

```
!mkdir szLocalDirectory
!cd szLocalDirectory
prompt
mget szRemoteDirectory/*
```

and that will download all files from szRemoteDirectory to newly created szLocalDirectory *without prompting for confirmation for each file*.

For more info, read the entire RFC959.

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask